# How to optimize performance for Virtualization?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, fedora

My PC has 2 GB of RAM and runs Windows 7. I installed VirtualBox with Fedora and set-aside 1 GB RAM in VirtualBox for this virtual environment.

I want to know how to improve the performance of Fedora in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable hardware virtualization if your CPU supports it.

Other than that, only thing you can do is to buy better hardware.

Comment: Where is this option in Windows 7?

Comment: @Rohit hardware virtualization (Intel VT, AMD-V) are typically enabled in the BIOS, not the OS. From my last few system builds I'm fairly sure it's on by default though. You can use Microsoft's hardware virtualization detection tool to find out if your machine supports it: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ee2a17f-8538-4619-8d1c-05d27e11adb2&displaylang=en

Comment: http://i51.tinypic.com/2cwsbk3.png

Comment: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt "Note
On many systems, the hardware virtualization features first need to be enabled in the BIOS before VirtualBox can use them."

Answer (score 4):

My first suggestion for any VirtualBox VM is to install the guest additions. They contain a lot of performance improvements, especially in the video department.

Answer (score 1):

Assign more CPUs to the VM. The performance will improve. It's fine to assign all your CPUs and memory to the VM as other systems will still work. The VM usually won't use all of the CPU time assigned to it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into safe mode and install guest additions to enable hardware acceleration for the graphics, i noticed that even though i wasn't playing games this still reduced the load on the CPU.